# php and javascript visual studio

Tags: json

put folder in desired order

Hey guys. In Visual Studio Code, the folders created are in alphabetical order. Example

folderCar
folderBook
folderMouse
folderProjector
folderKeyboard

Is there an extension for Visual Studio Code that makes it possible to leave the folders in the desired order. Example

folderProjector
folderMouse
folderBook
folderKeyboard
folderCar